# Turn off the touchpad every time I start linux

Tags: linux, bashrc, init

Im running a "bastard hodge-podge" Debian (sort of) linux based originally on pratham OS with quite a few things I had to build and install to get running

Simply need to turn off the infernal trackpad at start up

Presently I have to remember to open a terminal and run

synclient TouchpadOff=1

however, I invariably forget -- inability to type anything without it scrambling quickly reminds me.

How can I make this "Just run"?

Addit to .bashrc?

Comment: As part of the boot process? Use systemd or sysv init scripts (whatever you have installed).

Comment: Part of boot would be ideal. Would prefer to avoid systemd utterly, as I'm hoping to be rid of it very soon.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  If I could find a way to add it to bashrc would be best, as I reload the linux OS often

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at the man page of [synclient](ftp://www.x.org/pub/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/synclient.1.html), and it needs a running X server.

So the usual to place to put it would be in the display manager scripts or in your `.xsession` script, if your display manager still supports it (Gnome and KDE have changed this, not sure about the current state). Please edit your question and indicate which display manager you are using (`xdm`, `gdm`, `kdm`, `lightdm`, ...).

If you put it in `bashrc`, it will execute *every time you start a shell*. Even if the shell is run in an environment where no X server is active, and no touchpad is in use, e.g. if you `ssh` from the outside. So while this would probably work, logically it's the wrong solution, and I wouldn't recommend it.